# DriverManager class

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse, jdbc, database-connection

Can I get more technical info about the **DriverManager** class? I know that it's used to create the connection between java and a database (in my case I'm creating a db using MySQL). But should the DriverManager be created as a separate class in my project?

Comment: why would you want to have separate `DriverManager` class in your project?

Comment: I'd suggest not using `java.sql.DriverManager` at all. It's an evil hack.

Comment: `DriverManager` is included in Java, you don't need to create it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Surely you can, [read it here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/DriverManager.html). Normally you do not need to implement it, use the class from the system library.

If your are seriously interested in this class, look also into the [source code here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/sql/DriverManager.java).

Answer (score 0):

To know about Class you can view API http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/DriverManager.html

If you want to view source code , you can use Java decompiler (Ex : http://java.decompiler.free.fr/?q=jdgui

Comment: The source is included in the JDK, no need to use a decompiler.

Answer (score 0):

There are not much:

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/dbtest", "user", "password");
PreparedStatement pstmt = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM tbltest");
// Do things
// ...
pstmt.close();
conn.close();
```